# What hosted server configuration do I need to consider for a medium-performance web-application?

Tags: sql-server-2008, hosting, web-hosting

I have a Microsoft ASP.NET MVC web application with SQL Server 2008. Currently running on a single server, performance is reasonable. However I now need to deploy the same application to support much higher volumes. There are also a number of high-load services (for real-time route scheduling and processing of data feeds).

I believe that I will need a separate database server and one or two web-servers.

If I host at somewhere like 1&1 or Rackspace I presume they will advise. However I would like some idea before I start any discussions.

One area I'm not sure about is the windows server versions I should be using, CPU/memory requirements, whether these hosting providers offer load-balancing and kinds of costs involved.

EDITED:

I agree this is quite vague still. Perhaps I should post a question regarding the techniques for estimating server requirements? I'll search some previous posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However I now need to deploy the same application to support much higher volumes - 10,000 basic 
>   orders per week

Bad programmer? 10.000 oders per week are not a lot. assuming they come in 5 days and 8 hours (not all week long) that is still only 0.069 orders per second, or 4 orders per minute. Assuming a 3 times peak this still is just 12 orders per minute.

You need multiple servers for one order every 5 seconds? ;) Maybe you did not use any index on your database?

A small virtual server should be good enough.

Comment: On second read of my question, you are completely right this sounds like a low volume site that could be run on a single virtual server. I should have clarified. There are a number of services running that perform complex route scheduling and the processing of real-time feeds. The ordering part is only a small proportion of the load. I will update my question. Thanks TomTom.

Comment: Thanks, but then there simply is no answer possible. A note though - hosting like 1&1 will not carry oyou into good territory because yo uca nnot buy high performance servers. Mostly the disc IO subsystems suck. Like SUCK. I have a sql server running on 10 velcoraptor discs + SSD by now - no way to get that IO budget out of a stadnard server from a hoster.